# Selective Thresholding in OpenCV

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I am exploring OpenCV and struck at this point.
here wanted to do kind of selective threshold a image ,so that RGB / non-text image dont get distorted am able to do threshold to get the following result :
code :

```
Mat adap_threshold(Mat img)
{
    Mat img_gray;
    cvtColor(img, img_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    Mat thresh1;
    adaptiveThreshold(img_gray, thresh1, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, THRESH_BINARY, 21, 15); // BETTER
    // imshow("src", thresh1);

    // waitKey(0);

    return thresh1;
}
```

Output :
1.(Correct Result) 
[image]
[image]

2.(incorrect Result for non text / more rgb clustered image) 

Here in result 2 ,i only want to auto detect the desired part and apply threshold/enhancement there only.(look at rightmost output for expected output) 
[image]
[image]

3.Expected result of above image 
[image]

The expected output is result of enhancement done via optimizing the contrast and brightness of image. I am searching for a way to figure how can I **identify that a particular image can be enhanced via adaptive threshold or via contrast and brightness fix**.
How to fix this ?

Comment: Your “expected result” is not at all thresholded. Of course you can’t get that result with `adaptiveThreshold`!

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes u are right,let me reframe my question : the expected output is result of enhancement done via optimizing the contrast and brightness of image. I am searching for a way to figure how can i identify that a particular image can be enhanced via adaptive threshold or via contrast and brightness fix

Comment: split it in two different question, smaller problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


img = cv2.imread('LMZa7.jpg') # Read Image

#Here can do a histogram equalization to to improve contrast in image
#This step is optional according to your need.
img_yuv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)
img_yuv[:,:,0] = cv2.equalizeHist(img_yuv[:,:,0])
img_output = cv2.cvtColor(img_yuv, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR)


contrast =2
brightness= 25
#Here add contrast and brightness to image, this you can experiment.
out = cv2.addWeighted( img_output, contrast, img_output, 0, brightness)

#write image
cv2.imwrite("output.jpg",out)
```

Below is the final result.
[image]

Comment: How can i know when to apply "brightness and contrast adjustment" and "adaptive threshold"
i. how to find the right filter for a image automatically ?